# Symfony kernel.terminate EventListener not being called

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.2

Here's my service.yml

```
data_generate:
    class: AppBundle\Model\EventListener
    arguments: ["@service_container"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.terminate, method: onTerminate }
```

And the listener code

```
class EventListener{
    private $container;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container){
         $this->container = $container;
         $this->logger = $this->container->get('logger');
    }

    public function onTerminate(PostResponseEvent $event){
         $this->logger->info("test");
    }
}
```

Nothing is being logged.

I've also checked if the listener has been registered using

```
 php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.terminate
```

And here's the response

```
------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  Order   Callable                                                                            Priority  
 ------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  #1      AppBundle\Model\EventListener::onTerminate()                        0         
  #2      Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate()   0         
  #3      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate()    -1024     
 ------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
```

monolog config

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            channels: [!event]
        console:
            type:   console
            channels: [!event, !doctrine]
```

Is there any other configuration that I need to setup for kernel.terminate to work?

Comment: Check your application logs at `var/logs/dev.log`, maybe the propagation of the event is stopped by a listener with a higher priority of your

Comment: Nope, it's the highest priority. 
I've checked both var/logs/dev.log and nginx's logs as well.

Comment: Have you got this kind of log `event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener AppBundle\Model\EventListener` ?

Comment: @Mcsky. Nope nothing like that.

Comment: I think you already read this [doc'](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#the-kernel-terminate-event)
, your kernel MUST implement the `TerminableInterface` to the event be fired

Comment: Which environment are you using ? dev, prod ? can you paste your `monolog` config in `config_dev.yml` and `config_prod.yml` ?  Check that level is set to `debug` on you main handler. Monolog is not logging antyhing lower than your `level` setting.

Comment: @JulienBourdic, i'm on dev and I've edited the question to include the monolog config

Comment: @Mcsky. Just added the interface in the AppKernel class and it still doesn't work.

Comment: AppKernel extends a Kernel class that implement TerminableInterface, don't need to add that

Comment: Did you clear your cache ? :D
Try follow the proccess web/app.php and then the vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel::terminate function. THe event is fired in this class by Sf

Comment: Thanks @wnoveno, try to define explicitly the channel you want to use : `$this->logger->info('test', ['testChannel']);` and try to use `critical` instead of `info` (just a test)

Comment: Thanks @JulienBourdic. It was a monolog issue and not a kernel issue in the end.